# actionscript 3: default function parameter as an empty function?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

i have a function that receives a function as a parameter.
example:

```
function foo(bar:Function):void() {};
```

how can i set a default value for the function to be an empty function so the user will not have to paste a function as a parameter ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Functions are passed by reference, so this should work:

```
function foo(bar: Function = null): void {
  if(!bar) {
    // Replace null-ref with an empty function
    bar = function(): void {}
  }

  // Call given function
  bar();
}
```